# Cakephp: belongsto relation don't working in hasmany relation

Tags: php, cakephp, has-many, belongs-to

I have 3 models: messages, forums and users
A forum may have several messages and each message has posted by one user.

I would like to have in my forum model all messages and their owner.

So, in my Forum.php (model), I write:

```
public $belongsTo=array(
                'User' => array(
                                    'className' => 'User',
                                    'foreignKey'=>'id_user'
                                ),
                );

 public $hasMany=array(
                'Message' => array(
                                    'className' => 'Message',
                                    'foreignKey'=>'id_forum'
                                ),
                );
```

and in my Message.php (model) :

```
public $belongsTo=array(
                'User' => array(
                                    'className' => 'User',
                                    'foreignKey'=>'id_user'
                                ),
                );
```

With "debug($this->Forum->find('all'));", I get :

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Forum' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'titre' => 'rooo',
        'message' => 'tooo',
        'id_user' => '2',
        'date_create' => '2014-07-20 17:24:07'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '2',
        'username' => 'member',
        'date_sign' => '2014-07-04 11:34:52'
    ),
    'Message' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'message' => 'hi',
            'id_user' => '3',
            'id_forum' => '3',
            'date_add' => '2014-07-20 18:53:51'
        )
    )
)
```

)

But with "debug($this->Message->find('all'));", I get :

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Message' => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'message' => 'hi',
        'id_user' => '3',
        'id_forum' => '3',
        'date_add' => '2014-07-20 18:53:51'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '3',
        'username' => 'membre2',
        'date_sign' => '2014-07-20 18:26:41'
    )
)
```

)

I don't understand why I don't get my user informations on my 1st model but it's working in the 2nd.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: did you set recursive to 2 before find?   $this->Forum->recursive=2;

Comment: yep that's the answer
thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set recursive property of Forum modal to 2

```
$this->Forum->recursive=2;
```

For more information  [check here cakephp docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html)